# WP_query multiple custom fields not working

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

I am currently using WP 3.1 and trying to get WP_QUERY to work with the custom fields.  My argument is as follows:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'name',
        'value' => "$s",
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'address',
        'value' => "$s",
        'compare' => 'LIKE'

    )
  )
);
```

Basically searching the custom fields address and name, matching address OR name.

I am not getting any results and printing the SQL query I am getting:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'name'
AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%tom%'
AND mt1.meta_key = 'address'
AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%tom%'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

So not sure why the SQL is not showing OR, highlighted in bold, but showing AND.  I have also tried changing the relation, from OR to AND and the SQL remains identical.

Not sure what I am doing wrong having followed the documentation located at:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Also tried this:

```
$meta_query[] = array('key' => 'name','value' => $s ,'compare' => 'LIKE');
$meta_query[] = array('key' => 'address','value' => $s ,'compare' => 'LIKE');

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'relation' => 'OR',
'meta_query' => $meta_query
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Appreciate your help

Colin

Answer (score 1):

The functionality may not have been added until **after 3.1**.

The Codex refers to the latest version of WordPress. When in doubt, upgrade.

Comment: Okay, I'll upgrade however, with one parameter being passed, results are returned, same with changing address to "NOT LIKE" and its value. So it does seem to work.  Anyone else come across this problem?

Comment: 3.2 is not making a difference.  Surely the SQL should not be "AND" but "OR". Located at AND mt1.meta_key = 'address'. Bug?

Comment: Why not update to 3.5.1? It's difficult to help when you're using such as old version.

Comment: Can someone verify the code is correct, especially the second one?  Using two likes and the "relation" OR is in the correct location? Appreciated

Comment: See **Multiple Custom Field Handling** in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). The `relation` element should be inside `meta_query`.

Comment: If you look at the first code sample the user provided, the relation argument is indeed in the correct place.

Comment: @t31os My comment was regarding the second version of the code, and was in direct response to the OP's comment directly above my own.